# How to combine one-dimensional ruby arrays into a two-dimensional array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have two arrays:

- array of school names
- array of school slugs

Say the array of school names is: `[name1, name2, name3]` and of slug names are: `[slug1, slug2, slug3]`.

In ruby, how would I make an array `[[name1, slug1], [name2, slug2], [name3, slug3]]`.

My attempt at the matter is kind of `javascript-ish`:

```html
<% var schoolSelect = [];
for (var i=0; i<@schools.length; i++)
    schoolSelect[i] = [@schools.pluck(:name)[i], @schools.pluck(:slug)[i]]; %>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a ruby `for`.

Comment: Could be more like `(0..2).each do |position| ` code and also an `end`

Comment: Like I said, it was just an attempt haha - made it as best as I could in javascript form... I learned quickly that people don't like it when you don't post code so I posted something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will be using [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) for it like:

```
names = %w(name1 name2 name3)
slugs = %w(slug1 slug2 slug3)

names.zip(slugs)
# [["name1", "slug1"], ["name2", "slug2"], ["name3", "slug3"]]
```

Comment: nice approach. remove the commas though

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you consider a Hash for that data structure

```
schools = ["first", "second", "third"]
slugs = ["a", "b", "c"]
school_slugs = {}

(0..2).each do |position|
  school_slugs[schools[position]] = slugs[position]
end
# => 0..2
school_slugs
# => {"first" => "a", "second" => "b", "third" => "c"}
```

If you use Arup's approach you can also make that into a Hash, i.e.

```
[["name1", "slug1"], ["name2", "slug2"], ["name3", "slug3"]].to_h

# => {"name1"=>"slug1", "name2"=>"slug2", "name3"=>"slug3"}
```

Comment: May be you can use `each_with_object({})` insted of predefining `hash`

Answer (score 0):

```
names = %w(name1 name2 name3)
slugs = %w(slug1 slug2 slug3)
```

Whenever you have two arrays of the same size, as here,

```
names.zip(slugs)
  #=> [["name1", "slug1"], ["name2", "slug2"], ["name3", "slug3"]]
```

and

```
[names, slugs].transpose
  #=> [["name1", "slug1"], ["name2", "slug2"], ["name3", "slug3"]]
```

are interchangeable.